# Reference for Hodge decomposition for flag variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Any references for proof of the following facts:

1. The cohomology of the (complex) flag variety is always in $(p, p)$-type of Hodge Decomposition.
2. The natural map $G/T → G_\mathbb{C}/B$ is a diffeomorphism, where $G$ is compact connected real Lie group and $T$ is its maximal torus. $G_\mathbb{C}$ denote the complexification of $G$ and choose a Borel subgroup $B$ containing the complexification of $T$.

Comment: 1 : The cohomology of flag variety is generated by the Bialynicki-Birula cells which are algebraic so of type $(p,p)$ : a reference is the book "Complex geometry and representation theory" by Chriss and Ginzburg, chapter 3.

Comment: 2 : G being compact form of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$. Now using Iwasaw Decomposition for $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ we see that $G_{\mathbb{C}} = G.B$ and hence a surjective map $G \rightarrow G_{\mathbb{C}}/B$. One more observation is that $G \cap B = T$, since $G$ has only semisimple elements. Then we are done. Details can be looked up in the chapter Iwasawa decomposition in Lie Groups by D.Bump.